# Drupal voting module with an image per option

Tags: drupal, graphics, module, voting

I've searched for a while and can't find this option.

In Drupal 6.15 I'm trying to setup a Poll that will allow me to upload an image for each option to vote on, and have the image inline with the radio button.

Also I'd like to have a text field for each option to describe the image.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to check out the http://drupal.org/project/advpoll module...it allows HTML (and therefore images) in the choice selection, among other things that the core poll module lacks.

Comment: As of the latest version of Advanced Poll, it is no longer possible to insert html or images directly into the poll choice fields... see http://drupal.org/node/1649056#comment-6228794

Answer (score 1):

may be Fivestar? For text field use CCK.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Advanced Poll Field Image (sandbox module) for use with Advanced Polls:

http://drupal.org/sandbox/xandeadx/1871070